# vaex - create a dataframe from a list of lists

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, vaex

In Vaex's [docs](https://vaex.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html), I cannot find a way to create a dataframe from a list of lists.

In pandas I would simply do `pd.DataFrame([['A',1,3], ['B',2,4]])`.
How can this be done in Vaex?

Comment: more like a workaround, but couldn't you use `vaex.from_pandas`?

Comment: yeah, but I hoped I could avoid it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no method to read list of lists in vaex, however, there is [vaex.from_arrays()](https://vaex.io/docs/api.html#vaex.from_arrays) and it works like this:

```
vaex.from_arrays(column_name_1=list_of_values_1, column_name_2=list_of_values_2)
```

If you consider different python data structures, you may want to look at [vaex.from_dict()](https://vaex.io/docs/api.html#vaex.from_dict) or [vaex.from_items()](https://vaex.io/docs/api.html#vaex.from_items)

Since you already have the data in memory, you can use `pd.DataFrame(list_of_lists)` and then load it into vaex:

```
vaex.from_pandas(pd.DataFrame(list_of_lists))
```

You may want to `del` the list of lists data afterwards, to free up memory.